# Is there any real evidence to prove or disprove the existence of alien civilizations?

Tags: planet

Is there any *real* proof that alien civilizations exist in outer space? What if someone were to say that Earth is the only inhabited planet in the whole universe? How would you respond?

I need to write a five-paragraph argumentative essay to prove that alien civilizations exist. I need to write an introduction, three paragraphs supporting my statement that aliens exist, and a conclusion. In each of the three "body" paragraphs I need to describe in detail a piece of evidence supporting my claim.

I don't even know where to start. I mean, I want to find out the opinion of some scientists who think that we are alone, and then disprove their claim in my essay. I need to know the latest scientific evidence on the existence of alien civilizations. I don't mean like alien abduction stories or any of that science fiction stuff. I need some real proof that will be convincing and not undermine my argument.

How can you know for sure if there are alien civilizations in outer space? What do they look like? On which planets do they live? What kind of technology do they use? Why are we not alone in the universe? What evidence disproves the claims of Earth chauvinists?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is both a homework assignment and about aliens, which is not on-topic for Astronomy.

Comment: I think What_is_it basically answers this.   Proof isn't possible, pro or con.   Arguments can be made, see UFOs, Drake Equation, Steven Hawking's even warned us against trying to contact Aliens.   Wow signal, Roswell (hey, it's an argument), or for science, evidence that microbial life can exist in extreme environments like oceanic vents or on debris blown into space, and can possibly travel planet to planet.   5 paragraph's of arguments is easy.   Proof is impossible.   (Hope I haven't exceeded the homework help guideline in the above).

Comment: Proof is simple! Just one token made anytime. A civilization which wants to be known has no trouble doing so. But out of billions in reach for billions of years, none produced. That's pretty bad statistics for us who would like for some company out there. I'm afraid we have no one to fear, we're alone. Much like witch hunting was, just show me a trick of magic. We haven't gotten so far on the fundamental issues.

Comment: @HDE226868 I don't think the homework assignment argument is valid in this case. The OP is not doing a short answer or mathematical assignment, but a paper. Stack Exchange may be a valid source for the paper if cited properly. If we want to avoid giving him enough to copy/paste for his paper we can give him some talking points. SETI is on topic here.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any REAL proof that alien civilizations exist in outer space?

No.

> What if someone would say that Earth is the only inhabited planet in the whole Universe, how would you respond?

Depends on what their goal is. If their goal is to convince me of that, I'd just try to avoid the conversation. If their goal is to come to an understanding of the current body of scientific knowledge on the matter, I'd talk about how we don't know that that statement is true.

> I need to write a 5 paragraph argumentative essay to prove that alien civilizations exist. I need to write an introduction, 3 paragraphs supporting my statement that aliens exist, and a conclusion. In each of the three "body" paragraphs I need to describe in detail a piece of evidence supporting my claim.

That will be difficult, given that there is no such proof. Best you could do is argue that alien civilizations *likely* exist, given a certain set of *assumptions*.

> I don't even know where to start. I mean, I want to find out the opinion of some scientists who think that we are alone, and then disprove their claim in my essay.

That is not a good goal for an essay. Don't start with the goal of disproof. Start with the goal of understanding.

> I need to know the latest scientific evidence on the existence of alien civilizations. I don't mean like alien abduction stories or any of that science fiction stuff. I need some real proof that will be convincing and not undermine my argument.

Look at the [Drake Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation) and [recent research that concludes that there are many planets in the galaxy](http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2012-01/new-exoplanet-analysis-determines-planets-are-more-common-stars-milky-way).

> How can you know for sure if there are alien civilizations in outer space?

You would need observational evidence.

> What do they look like? On which planets do they live? What kind of technology do they use?

All unknown.

> Why are we not alone in the Universe?

This question presumes the conclusion that we are not alone. We might be alone.

> What evidence disproves the claims of Earth chauvinists?

None.

Comment: @Galaxy: This assessment essentially correct. I don't know why your teacher gave you such a nonsensical assignment. We can't prove or disprove that alien civilizations exist, we simply don't know. Possibly however your assigment is rather about learning the ways to assess such a question.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape it's a strange assignment and I'd guess the teacher isn't a science guy if he's asking for proof.    If he's asking for arguments to be made, then it's perfectly fine, cause arguments can be made pro or con.   Proof on the other hand, can't.